# RichTextBlock flow with InlineUIContainer

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a `RichTextBlock` in `RichTextColumns` as in the `ItemDetailPage` in the default VS2012 template. My `RichTextBlock` consists of text paragraphs that are neatly laid out and broken into columns.

I want to insert an `Image` to the `RichTextBlock` and the end after all the text paragrahs. If I insert the image using this code

```
<Paragraph LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight">
    <InlineUIContainer>
       <Image Height=".." Width=".." />
  </InlineUIContainer>
</Paragraph>
```

The problem is, that if there is not enough place in the last column, the image is not shown in full, it is cut at bottom. How to I make the `RichTextBlock` generate another column and move the Image there to shown it in full?

I tried changind the `LineStackingStrategy` of the Paragraph but it did not help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I modeled my extra InlineUIContainers after the one in the gridview template.  However, I had to add a LineHeight attribute that matched my control height.  This works for some reason.

```
<Paragraph x:Name="rectPara" LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight" LineHeight="400">
    <InlineUIContainer x:Name="rectUICont" >
          <Canvas x:Name="d3dCanvas" MaxHeight="400" Margin="0,20,0,10" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="True" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
                <Rectangle x:Name="d3dRectangle" Fill="{Binding RectangleFill}"  Stroke="Red" Height="400" Width="400"  />
          </Canvas>
     </InlineUIContainer>
</Paragraph>
```

Comment: This works but when this paragprah is move to a new column it also creates another new empty column